# Uploading apkg file with paperclip on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, upload, paperclip, file-extension

I am trying to create a rails app that will upload Anki decks (apkg file extension) using paperclip. The error I am getting states:

> "File has an extension that does not match its contents."

I am wondering what is the correct way to file map this extension. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're running into Paperclip's file type validations. There's apparently a bunch of different things that can trigger this message. If, for instance, you're running on Windows, you have to [manually install the file utility](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#file). As of version 4.0.0, [every upload model needs to have a filetype validation of some sort, and has an un-removable validation to protect against filetype spoofing](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#security-validations).

I don't actually know which of these you're running into, but that same link suggests solutions to each. 
If you don't have any kind of filetype validation, you probably need to add some:

```
validates_attachment_file_name :column_name, :matches => [/apkg\Z/]
```

or, if not feeling security-conscious:

```
do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :column_name
```

For the second, well, I'm just going to quote the docs:

> [The unavoidable spoofing check] can sometimes cause false validation errors in applications that
>   use custom file extensions. In these cases you may wish to add your
>   custom extension to the list of file extensions allowed for your mime
>   type configured by the mime-types gem:
>
> ```
> # Allow ".foo" as an extension for files with the mime type "text/plain".
> text_plain = MIME::Types["text/plain"].first
> text_plain.extensions << "foo"
> MIME::Types.index_extensions text_plain
> ```